# c# wpf combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change second combobox based on first selection. For first combobox i am getting data from table in database.

```
           {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = autoser; Integrated Security = true");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select  id_type,type FROM types", conn);


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "types");



        typescb.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        typescb.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["type"].ToString();
        typescb.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id_type"].ToString();

    }
```

For example if in first combobox i choose truck in second should display a list of truck, or if i choose car, the in second should appear a list of car that are in my database. I looked some posts in this site, they didn't help me, so i am posting this question. Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: google cascading drop downs. This is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you've selected a category (aka an item from your first `ComboBox`), such as *car*, you can read data from the database, where your vehicles are being stored, than you can filter them by the type "*car*".

For example in LINQ:

```
var cars = readFromDbList.Where(item => item.Type == "car");
```

Of course, this example is using the type as string, and the `item` object has a `Type` property, but you would use your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about using WPF is using the bindings to update the UI. In this case you are trying to force the UI to update. Your UI should update based on changes to the underline data model.  I would recommend using SQLMetal to generate an ORM layer, LINQ to get your data, and WPF to render.

I wrote an article some time ago on setting it up.
http://netlegger.blogspot.ca/2013/05/using-linq-to-sql-with-sqlmetal-wpf.html

When you have everything setup, your binding can be triggered based on property change event. Anything you change in the underline data model will be reflected in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should be code on SelectIndexChange event..

con.Open();
  string str = "select * from Tablename where CarName='" + ComboBox1.Text + "'" Groupby CarName;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                ComboBox1.Text = dr["CarName"].ToString();

```
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this code, but in second combobox is appearing me anything